# I'm having trouble formulating a cooking energy-efficiency question. Any suggestions?

Tags: discussion

For a while I've been thinking off-and-on about energy efficiency in cooking, partly prompted by camping methods, but more in the context of domestic frugality. Some methods are obvious, like lids on pans and not boiling more water than you need, but there are many others.

I'd like to ask a question to explore some of the possibilities, but anything I can come up with would seem to either

1. prompt a big list of tips (*"How can I use less energy when cooking?"*); or
2. be very specific: something about pot skirts on domestic gas for example (which I actually might do on its own), or which starchy sides cook well by soaking then heating instead of boiling.

I'd like to go for the more exploratory/general question, but does anyone have any ideas on how it would work well? Or should I just ask away and see what happens?

Comment: The recent [salt/frugal](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/94256/20413) question prompted me to finally get round to thinking a bit more about this, as it suggests a wider interest.